# Spring data jpa dynamic query not working for Date type parameter

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and for generating dynamic query I use Spring Data JPA Specifications. It works correct beside for type Date. I am getting the following exception:

```
 Parameter value [2017-06-01] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2017-06-01] did not match expected type [java.time.LocalDate (n/a)]]
```

but parameter value that I pass in is java.util.Date type. What can be reason ?

Here is my entity:

```
private String name;

@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long userId;

@Column(name = "version_id")
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long versionId;

@Column(name = "created_date")
private LocalDate createdDate;
```

Here is

```
public ViewDetailSpecificationsBuilder createSearchSpecifications(ViewSearch view) {
    ViewDetailSpecificationsBuilder builder = new ViewDetailSpecificationsBuilder();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(view.getName())) {
        builder.with("name", Operation.DEFAULT, view.getName());
    }       
    if (view.getStartDate() != null) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(view.getStartDate(), formatter);
        builder.with("createdDate", Operation.GREATHERTHANEQUALTO, date);
    }
    if (view.getVersion() != null) {
        builder.with("version", Operation.DEFAULT, view.getVersion());
    }
    return builder;
}
```

This throws below exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [Thu%Jun%01%00:00:00%AMT%2017] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Thu%Jun%01%00:00:00%AMT%2017] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

If I formatted startDate (formatter.format(startDate)) it throws above exception.

Comment: show more code. Specifically where you pass in the value

Answer (score 0):

No, you're either passing a `String` or a `java.sql.Date`

Comment: I have change it to java.time.LocalDate but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Make sure it's a `java.util.Date`